# What do we mean by the word "distinct" in this book?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> What do we mean by the word "distinct" in the first line of the first article *Number* in [this book](https://archive.org/stream/thenumbersystemo17920gut/17920-pdf#page/n11/mode/2up)?

This is the line: "We say of certain ***distinct*** things that they form a group when we
make them collectively a single object of our attention."

Example: Suppose a collection of three coins(may be of same or different value) in my pocket. I call the collection of these three coins **A**. Let's name the three coins **C_1,C_2** and **C_3**. So  **A** can be written as **A={C_1,C_2,C_3}**. Let **C_1** and **C_3** be of same value(say 1 rupee each). Are **C_1** and **C_2** still distinct from each other?

> Does the word "*distinct*" have some other meaning in Fine's book as compared to the general meaning of the English word "*distinct*"?

---

<sup>**Note: this question is also being asked at Math.SE

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732370/what-do-we-mean-by-the-term-number-of-things/743660#743660**</sup>

Comment: The basic sense of "distinct" is "different". In the context of mathematics, we prefer the word "distinct" to "different". Also, those distinct objects don't have to be abstract ones. (Check out this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29.) Above all, don't confuse the object itself with its value. If you have a set of three different (distinct) objects, it doesn't matter whether any two of them will share some properties or not. Objects are objects. Their properties (or values of their properties) are irrelevant to the discussion in the book.

Comment: Note the following link may help readers focus more on your question:  http://books.google.com/books?id=KWRHAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA3&ots=eygOiyzqS2&dq=%22We%20say%20of%20certain%20distinct%20things%20that%20they%20form%20a%20group%22%20%22when%20we%20make%20them%20collectively%20a%20single%20object%20of%20our%20attention%22&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=%22We%20say%20of%20certain%20distinct%20things%20that%20they%20form%20a%20group%22%20%22when%20we%20make%20them%20collectively%20a%20single%20object%20of%20our%20attention%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

In set theory, the only concern for "distinctness" is whether or not items have different names.  Different names = Distinct.

Items can share a property (such as male/female or the value of a coin) and still be distinct items.  Consider the following:

Set1 = {John, Joe, Mary}

We know John and Joe are "male" and "Mary" is female.  Do we have three distinct "things"?  Yes.

On the other hand, consider 3 people:  Joe McDonald, Joe Harris, Jane Fonda.  What is the set of all first names?  It's {Joe, Jane}.  There are only two distinct first names.

You have three different coins.  They are distinct because each is a different coin and you gave each one a different name.

Comment: It should be noted that my question is not about set theory. I am asking for the general meaning of the word "_distinct_". Moreover the collection of coins in my pocket is not a _set_ because coins are not _abstract objects_.

Comment: Bytheway what are the properties of my coins which are distinct? How can you differentiate b/w two coins of same value, same wieght, same everything. Now you will say the coins are spatially distingiushable. Then consider a group {A,A,A} Would first A be distinct from the second A?

Comment: A set does not have to contain abstract objects. You are not asking about the general meaning of "distinct"; you are asking about its meaning in the context of book on mathematics. If you want to generalize your question, you should remove that specific context :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I thought you were asking for an answer related to the question you asked. Here's a great reference for general definitions (and much faster than asking here):  http://lmgtfy.com/?q=definition+distinct

Comment: Please consider all of my answers as (a) sincere and (b) with a bit of "having fun". I'm really here to help. (1) "Spatially distinguishable" would be a perfectly fine and acceptable way to tell the difference between three coins.  People do this all the time when counting change to pay for something. If you wanted to get technical, you could also use a scale or calipers with enough precision to determine minute differences in (2) diameter or (3) weight, since they are *"real coins"*.  You could also use a high powered microscope to find (4) minute forensic differences such as small marks.

Comment: I sense you're defending a position on this. If you made a bet with someone, I'm sorry but you lost. But I can give you some relief: Within your own personal understanding/belief-system/definitions of "distinct", "collection", and "group", you are "concluding" that "you are right". And neither I nor any mathematician can argue against your "right-ness" in this sense. *Based on **your** definitions, you are right.* However, from the standard point of view of mathematics, from what you described, they are three distinct items.

Comment: The problem I am having is that the Fine's book is incorrect. This book says number of things in the group {A,A,A} is one because all A's are identical. This is plain wrong .

Comment: My main question is this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732370/what-do-we-mean-by-the-term-number-of-things/742365?noredirect=1#comment1549280_742365. In genral when we say there are three coins in my pocket we do not consider their distinction. Similarily if someone asks me how many letters are in group {A,A,A} then i would say 3 but acc. to fines book it should be 1 which is wrong.

Comment: Everyone is misunderstanding me e.g [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10622/what-do-we-mean-by-the-term-number-of-things#comment27100_10622). The _term number of things_ in set means number of distinct of abstract objects. In usual life the term _number of things_ applies to even indistinguishable things.

Comment: You seem to be a kind person please help me in understanding this heck.

Comment: The reason this bothers you is because you don't like irrationality. You actually have the mark of a mathematician-in-the-making to fight for what you believe is rational. It's not a matter of right and wrong. It's a matter of definitions.  Your definition *leads to* "3" and theirs *lead to* "1". In mathematics, you need to replace "belief" with "axiom", and say, "given my axioms and definitions and rules, the answer is 3, but given their axioms and definitions and rules, the answer is 1."  I'll take a look over there...

Comment: Give me a few minutes to answer to the people at both sites... I know exactly what you are saying and I think I can clear it up.

Comment: Sir, someone has told me [something very useful](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10622/what-do-we-mean-by-the-term-number-of-things/10624#comment27107_10624) which concludes that the _number of things_ in the group {A,A,A} are 3.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Maybe the problem isn't about "distinct". One possible problem is that the book has no definition of the word "thing(s)". What is "thing"? If we can be clear about what "thing" is, then we can be certain of what {A,A,A} is, and also the number of things in {A,A,A}. Without such a definition, we have a few choices, such as a) get along with the book, trying to make senses of it; b) argue that the book is wrong; or c) regard the book as a badly written one. That's my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

*Does the word "distinct" have some other meaning in Fine's book as compared to the general meaning of the English word "distinct"?*

**Yes!** When you have a math book, there are a lot of terms that become highly specialized jargon, and the words no longer mean what regular people might mean in English. (Logic classes also do this.)

So to understand the math book's usage, you have to look at what the *book* is defining "distinct" to mean, in that distinct (ha!) case. So when you look it up in the dictionary (e.g., dictionary.reference.com ), you go looking to see if there is a "math" definition. In the case of http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distinct , I scroll waaaaay down and it says: "(maths, logic) (of a pair of entities): not identical". As you can tell by the term "maths" instead of "math," that's a British definition. Since you're working from an older book, perhaps less deviated from British English (or written by a British author in the first place), the chances are high that that's the definition you want.

Comment: I could not find the "math" definition in that link.

Comment: Are **C_1** and **C_2** distinct from each other?

Comment: 1: The "math" definition is in that link, very near the bottom. I just found it there again. Use your browser's "search" function to search for the word "Math" and you will find it. 2: Probably, because of the _1 and _2 components, but you'll have to see if your *book* defines them as distinct in whatever math problem it has. I have forgotten most math past simple algebra, so look for a mathematics expert for math answers.